# Auto-generate field value on sfGuardUser when registering

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard, autogeneratecolumn

I'm building a Symfony 1.4 project that is using [sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) for users/authentication.  I have a field on my user table named "access_token" that I would like to populate with an auto-generated value upon user registration.  I see that for registration, the `sfGuardRegisterForm` is used for validation.  Unfortunately, when I run `./symfony doctrine:build-forms` from the command line, this form doesn't appear to be extended, meaning that I can't generate an access token there without editing the plugin.

Alternatively, I was thinking of modifying the `sfRequest` parameters such that I manually set the "access_token" value before attempting to validate via this form.  However, since I'm allowing users to register both by a frontend application as well as an API application, this means that I would have to make sure I manually stuff this parameter value in both places, which seems inefficient.  However, perhaps that is actually the right way to go, and trying to modify the form is not ideal.

Any input/suggestions?  Would anyone do anything different than the ideas I have listed here?

**Edit**: I've already create a public static method on my `sfGuardUser` model named `generateAccessToken`, which returns the value.  I'm just trying to figure out the best place to call this in my project's code.

Comment: Does your `access_token` depends on current request?

Comment: The generation of the access_token does not depend upon the current request.  It will be random, unique, and private, but not based upon the request at all.  It will be used later (post-registration) when making API calls on behalf of the user, at which point it will be included as a URL parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sfDoctrineGuardPlugin does not provide user registration functionality. This why you have to implement it on your own. So, in your controller you can populate a field just the way it's being done with symfony:

```
class myActions extends sfActions {
    public function executeRegistration(sfWebRequest $request) {
        ...
        $form = new myRegisterForm();
        $form->setDefault('access_token', sfGuardUser::generateAccessToken());
        ...
    }
}
```

And the `access_token` widget should be an instance of `sfWidgetFormInputHidden`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Darmen - I see the plugin includes `sfGuardRegisterForm` (https://github.com/pocky/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/blob/master/lib/form/doctrine/sfGuardRegisterForm.class.php), which extends `BasesfGuardRegisterForm` (https://github.com/pocky/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/blob/master/lib/form/doctrine/base/BasesfGuardRegisterForm.class.php).  I would expect I should be extending from the former class (or simply using the former class), is that right?  I guess one of the reasons I thought this is I'd like to run `./symfony guard:create-user` and have it properly use my register form to populate the fields.

Comment: Ok, it has a predefined form, but hasn't any action for registration functionality — that's what I mean. Just extend from `sfGuardRegisterForm`, add `access_token` widget and write your own controller.

`./symfony guard:create-user` task is independent and does not use any form because it's a cli, not a controller that uses user input.

Matt, did I understand you right?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see that in the code now. Thanks so much for all the help, I really appreciate it as a Symfony novice! :)